# Can a callback function be an object that stores properties within itself?

Tags: javascript

The following test code works properly.  A `mousemove` event triggers the `checkPosition` function which stores the mouse position inside the object `mousePosition`.

```js
"use strict";

const mousePosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

function checkPosition(e) {
    mousePosition.x = e.clientX;
    mousePosition.y = e.clientY;
}
    
addEventListener("mousemove", checkPosition);
addEventListener("click", () => console.log(mousePosition) );
```

However I'd like to simplify this if possible. Is there a way to store the mouse position inside of the callback function?  I've tried this a bunch of different ways and I'm having no luck.

The code below doesn't work but hopefully it shows what I'm trying to accomplish.  I know my syntax must be screwed up but I don't know how to construct this.  Thanks so much!

```js
"use strict";

const mousePosition = (e) => {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
};
    
addEventListener("mousemove", mousePosition);
addEventListener("click", () => console.log(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named function to provide access to the function's own object:

```
"use strict";

const mousePosition = function f(e) {
  f.x = e.clientX;
  f.y = e.clientY;
};

addEventListener("mousemove", mousePosition);
addEventListener("click", () => console.log(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y));
```

The use of the function's local name `f` internally within the `mousePosition` function is necessary to ensure that the properties get stored on the given function, regardless of whether some other piece of code replaces the external variable `mouseFunction` with something else.

[notwithstanding that `const` should prevent that, it's still not good practise to refer to an object's external name from within that object]

In pre-ES5 code you could have used `arguments.callee.<property>` but strict mode prohibits that.

Comment: Very interesting, I see your point.  I was experimenting with arrow functions to reduce syntax.  I hadn't yet figured out that in this case I needed a named function to target the properties inside.  Perfect!

Comment: Explanation and reasoning is good in general, but in this scenario how can someone replace `mouseFunction `? It's a constant.

Comment: I don't think they can (although I addressed that in my answer).  Either way, it's something best avoided IMHO.

Comment: Yes, it is a good coding practice in general, but for very short code snippets, I don't mind not following the good coding practice if that makes the code more complex or less elegant. For long and complex code, following the good coding practice is a must.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by adding the `x` and `y` properties dynamically like this:

```js
"use strict";

const mousePosition = (e) => {
  mousePosition.x = e.clientX;
  mousePosition.y = e.clientY;
};

addEventListener("mousemove", mousePosition);
addEventListener("click", () => console.log(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y));
```

Comment: That works!  I had tried using the `this` keyword and it didn't work.  I never thought to use `mousePosition` directly.  Perfect!

Comment: Please don't use arrow functions like this - it breaks the maxim that an object shouldn't refer to itself via the name it's known by outside.  If OTOH you use `const mousePosition = function f(e) { f.x = e.clientX; ... }` then you avoid this because the function's given name is implicitly in the scope of the function, but not _outside_ of it.

Comment: @Alnitak Although I agree with you in general, it seems fine to me in this scenario.